# Tools for organizing benchmark reports

Tags: automation, software-testing, performance-analysis, benchmarking

I have an open-source project. We have some benchmarks.

For simplicity, let's assume that the output of each benchmark is a 2-D plot (i.e. a vector of [x, y] pairs).

Then, we have releases. After each release, I want to run all benchmarks, store their results, and generate reports from them.

Report from each release should be a set of plots, one plot for each benchmark. I want to be able to browse those plots by release and to compare plots from different releases (i.e. show the results of the same benchmark from different releases on one plot).

Ideally, reports should be static HTML + JavaScript, so that I don't need a server to browse them and can just upload them to github pages.

Could someone recommend open-source tools that solve this or similar problem? Maybe I'm googling this wrong, but I haven't find any ready-to-use solution. On the other hand, this sounds like a pretty common use case, doesn't it?

Currently I'm using Google Benchmark (C++ library). I could code this by myself by parsing it's JSON output and generating reports using plotly (python library) or similar tool. However, I'd prefer to use some existing solution, if it exists.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Pandas!